# Updating a panel in GTK+3 via user input

Tags: c, gtk3, file-browser

Im new to GTK and dont quite understand how to use g_signal_connect().  I am building a basic file browser so far it has two panels one with a directory view and one with a file view

```
#include <pwd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <limits.h>

#include "ListView/buildList.h"
#include "TreeView/buildTree.h"

#define MAX_PATH 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    GtkTreeStore *store_tree = gtk_tree_store_new (COLUMNS, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING);
    GtkTreeStore *store_list = gtk_tree_store_new (COLUMNS, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING);
    char *working_dir = getenv("HOMEs");
    if (working_dir != NULL) {
        printf("Home dir in enviroment ");
        printf("%s\n", working_dir);
    }
    else {
        working_dir = pwd();
        if(working_dir != NULL){
            printf("Failed to find Home using current directory \n");
        }
        else{
            printf("Directory error terminate");
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    GtkTreeIter iter_p;
    if(list_dir(store_tree, working_dir, iter_p, 0) != 0){
        printf ("Error building tree");
        return 1;
    }
    if(build_list(store_list, working_dir) != 0){
        printf ("Error building tree");
        return 1;
    }
    //build first two views, tree and list.
    GtkWidget *treeview = gtk_tree_view_new ();
    GtkWidget *listview = gtk_tree_view_new ();
    build_treeview(treeview);
    build_listview(listview);

    GtkTreeSelection *selection;
    selection = gtk_tree_view_get_selection (GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview));
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(selection), "changed", 
                      G_CALLBACK(item_selected), NULL);

    gtk_tree_view_set_model (GTK_TREE_VIEW (treeview), GTK_TREE_MODEL (store_tree));
    gtk_tree_view_set_model (GTK_TREE_VIEW (listview), GTK_TREE_MODEL (store_list));

    g_object_unref (store_tree);
    g_object_unref (store_list);

    display (treeview, listview);

    gtk_main ();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to be able to detect when the user selects a directory and change the file panel to display the new files.  Right now when it detects a change it simply outputs to console some information given to it by `selection` looking at the documentation is seems like G_CALLBACK can only  be given two arguments a pointer to data and the selection.

Im wondering if there is some way to use GTK to wait for a change of directories and update the file panel

/*notes

treeview: is one column which is a gtk_tree structure

list_dir: recursivly creates subtree of directories from some path in store_tree

listview: one column which is Name which contains names of the file

build_list: treeview when selected can return the path to that dir.  store all files in directory in gtk_store store_list

Comment: A `G_CALLBACK` taking two arguments is a consequence of function pointers being typed in C. In reality the signal handler should have whatever arguments the signal's documentation tells you it should. But you cast it with `G_CALLBACK()` so that it fits in the signature of `g_signal_connect()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `gtk_tree_view_get_selection` gets executed before the window of your application is displayed. It thus will be always(!) empty and since an empty selection will never be changed you will never receive the `"changed"` signal.

The signal hookup itself is correct.